# In Which Province is a Post Code (Adding Attribute from Another Layer)?

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I have two polygon shapefiles. One is post codes, the other is provinces (in China). I'd like to add a "Province" field to the post code database (i.e. DBF file). This field would indicate the province for each post code. Note - post codes never cross province boundaries.

How would I do this? I'm using QGIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably do the following:

1. `Vector > Geometry Tools > Polygon Centroids...` on your *Province* shapefile.
2. `MMQGIS > Combine > Spatial Join` on your *Postcode* and *Province centroid* layers and select which fields you want to keep in the output:

[image: MMQGIS Spatial Join]

---

Note that you may need to download/install the MMQGIS plugin from `Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins...`.